# IntelliJ IDEA interactive rebase fails with "cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory"

Tags: git, intellij-idea, rider, git-for-windows

On Windows, when I try to perform an interactive rebase, IntelliJ IDEA fails with the following error:

> cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory unable to start editor '"V:/tools/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3/jbr/bin/java" -cp "V:/tools/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3/plugins/git4idea/lib/git4idea-rt.jar;V:/tools/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3/lib/xmlrpc-2.0.1.jar;V:/tools/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3/lib/commons-codec-1.13.jar" git4idea.rebase.GitRebaseEditorMain 63342'

Most of the other git operations work.

I tried reinstalling Git for Windows, and IntelliJ, among other things.

Strangely, I noticed that the interactive rebase works on Jetbrains Rider.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple `git.exe` executables within Git for Windows. The selected one in the settings may not be the correct one.

In the *Settings | Version Control | Git* configuration, check the path to the Git executable.

It must **not** be `Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`.

Instead, use `Git\cmd\git.exe`.